# Is moderator Maulik V ok?

Tags: support

I haven't seen moderator Maulik V around for some time. Is he ok? Does SE try to look after their moderators if they go missing?

**Note:**

I don't care how active he's "meant to be". I just care if he's ok or not.

Comment: SE does pay attention to mod absences; in fact, the mod and CM tools list mods along with their last active dates, and there's a built-in tool for marking vacations etc in advance so others can plan around absences.

Comment: A very good question. The community should have some kind of ways to look for the whereabouts of their mods/members.

Comment: IIRC if a mod disappears for a six whole months or some other timeframe, they would be revoked of their diamond-ship and the team will investigate. Usually, mods can/should inform if they're leaving for a considerably long time. I don't think Maulik has left for long enough to qualify for any of that though, maybe that was just my impression.

Comment: [He's still active](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3187/maulik-v?tab=activity&sort=all&page=1), although I don't know if he's less active than a moderator ought to be.

Comment: @M.A.R. it's more like two years...

Comment: @Cat you mean Maulik's leave, or the time it takes for the mod status to be removed? Either way, I forgot to mention in my previous comment that such recourse is reserved for the most extreme cases, and a moderator's usually not required to do much more than handling a bunch of flags. Most stuff mods do are not moderator duties, but just stuff they voluntarily do for the community.

Comment: @M.A.R. One of the Cooking mods was absent for a while... I thought it was longer but it was apparently only [a year](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2257/thanks-to-aaronut-for-his-years-of-service#comment6280_2257) but it wasn't six months. My understanding is that they tend to attempt to communicate with the mod before removing their status.

Comment: @Man_From_India Anyone can look at a user's profile page and see the last time they visited the site: http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3187/maulik-v?tab=profile He hasn't been away long enough that I think we should be too worried, although I do hope it's good things keeping him busy.

Comment: @ColleenV Me too ... (hoping it's good things keeping him busy)

Comment: He [answered](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/122606/1694) two questions on March 15 but he hasn't posted any questions since September of last year. So it's not as if he's been gone for months. I know Maulik was a very positive force and an active  member on ELL. If he reads your question, I'm sure he'll be touched by your concern.